# "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero"

Tags: c#

This code reads from log files, and if any of the lines contain -r and a user.Handle, it will replace the -r with an ^ cut off everything before ^, cut off everything after the :, and then save the remaining text. I'm getting the error specified in the title ONLY SOMETIMES

```
if (line.Contains(user.Handle) && line.Contains("-r"))
{
    string a = line.Replace("-r", "^");
    string b = a.Substring(a.IndexOf('^') + 1);
    string c = b.Substring(0, b.IndexOf(':'));
    if (!isDuplicate(c))
    {
        listViewEx1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(user.Handle)
        {
            SubItems = { c }
        });
        dupCheck.Add(c);
        logcount++;
    }
```

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on? Could you post your stack trace?

Comment: The [`string.Substring` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you're calling has a parameter named `length`. You're passing in the result of `b.IndexOf(':')`, which can be less than zero. This is nothing that the exception didn't *already* tell you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a frequent mistake in .NET when using the Substring method. People often think that the Substring takes the start and end index which is wrong. It takes the start index and the length. For example:

```
string str = "ABC123";

int length = str.Length - str.IndexOf("1") + 1;
string sub = str.Substring(0, length); // ABC1
```

Or better, create an extension method for this reusable piece to add the Java Like Substring in C# that takes a start and end index:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static string SubstringRange(this string str, int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        if (startIndex > str.Length - 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(startIndex));
        if (endIndex > str.Length - 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(endIndex));

        return str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1);
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
string str = "ABC123";

string sub2 = str.SubstringRange(str.IndexOf("B"), str.IndexOf("2")); // BC12
```